# QScintilla in PySide

Tags: python, editor, pyside, qscintilla

I like PySide, and have used it for a while now, but in the program I am working on at the moment, I need an advanced code editor.

I have found [QScintilla](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/qscintilla/intro), but that is for PyQt. Is that compatible with PySide and if so, how would I go about using it?
I have also looked at [PySide-QScintilla](http://gitorious.org/pyside-qscintilla), but all that is is a couple of `.h` files and an `__init.py__` and the `__init__.py` doesn't even have anything relating to the `.h` files! Has anyone used that? How do you include it in a program?
I also saw [qutepart](https://qutepart.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) but it seems to be mush too basic for what I need.

I would accept solutions other than QScintilla, but they have to have:

- Error Highlighting
- Syntax Highlighting
- Code Suggestion (a drop down menu while typing)
- Line Numbers
- Custom Colors
- Must be at least GPL (LGPL would be nice)

Any other features are great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a quick Google search brought up the following:

- http://gitorious.org/pyside-qscintilla
- https://github.com/LuaDist/scintilla/tree/master/qt/ScintillaEditPy

I suspect the first one is a direct port, whereas the second is some kind of Scintilla wrapper instead of a QScintilla port.

Comment: How would you use it in a program (as in what would you import)? Do you need to build it with cmake or qmake or something else? A little more information would be helpful.